How to update a data extension upon click from a CTA in an email
How to update a data extension from a CTA click in an email
Recently I have been asked to create an email whereby when the user clicks a link or button, it executes an UpsertDE to my chosen data extension.  I saw from another post about using form submit where an if...then code block would call the UpsertDE function. However when I try that bit of code shown below (borrowed from the other thread), it doesn't work unless I remove the if..then, but then it fires the UpsertDE upon send, as that is when the AMPScript is executed.
I tried a couple of things like setting up an HMTL form but I am not able to solve it with that either.
I know I can set up a Cloud Page and redirect to the cloud page, but my ask is to do it all from within an email, and only up user clicking the CTA.
Here is the code I borrowed.
%%[
var @reservationid, @hotel_name, @city, @country, @fromdate, @todate, @value, 
@customerid,@reservationstatus
set @reservationid = RequestParameter("reservationid")
set @reservationstatus = RequestParameter("reservationstatus")
set @customerid = RequestParameter("customerid")
set @hotel_name = RequestParameter("hotel_name")
set @city = RequestParameter("city")
set @country = RequestParameter("country")
set @value = RequestParameter("value")
set @fromdate = RequestParameter("fromdate")
set @todate = RequestParameter("todate")
set @salutation = RequestParameter("salutation")
set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
set @lastname = RequestParameter("lastname")



Var @Submit
Set @Submit = RequestParameter('submitted')
If @Submit == 'submitted' Then
UpsertDE('Final_Task_Table',1,'reservationid',@reservationid,'reservationstatus', 'cancelled')
Endif
]%%


All the lines with RequestParameter are expecting data to be posted from a form, or included as URL parameters. It looks like you only need reservationid?
%%[
var @reservationid, @confirm
set @reservationid = RequestParameter("reservationid")
set @updateReservation = UpsertDE('Final_Task_Table',1,'reservationid',@reservationid,'reservationstatus', 'cancelled')
]%%

The above will work, but IMHO you should have a more robust solution. Some email provides visit all links in your emails, to scan for potential malicious sites and threats. This will instantly cancel many of your reservations.
Instead you should have a two-step approach:
%%[
var @reservationid
set @reservationid = RequestParameter("reservationid")
set @confirm = RequestParameter("confirm")
IF empty(@reservationid) THEN
]%% 
<b>You must provide your reservation ID</b>
%%[
ELSE
IF EMPTY(@confirm) THEN
]%%
<b>%%=Concat('Are you sure you want to cancel reservation with ID: ',@reservationid,'?')=%%</b><br>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesUrl(1234,"reservationid",@reservationid,"confirm","yes"))=%%">Yes, please cancel</a>
%%[
ELSE 
set @updateReservation = UpsertDE('Final_Task_Table',1,'reservationid',@reservationid,'reservationstatus', 'cancelled')
ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%

Can you follow my thinking here?

This whole topic is very relevant e.g. also for unsubscription in B2b where enterprise infrastructure is on the receiving end.
What Lukas said is probably the best thing if the usecase lends itself to a confirmation step. Don't process clicks, but send people to confirmation pages, until you actually process.
==
Adding to what he said, there are two problems that you need to tackle or you will get unstable behavior.

recipient side "bots" (security features) that click ALL links by default. (See Lukas' point)

recipient side tools that "verify" all links by clicking them first when you click them; Meaning anything I click in my outlook gets tracked twice, and I can see different IPs (one from Microsoft, one my own) (-> that is outlook safelinks). You might not want your wanted behavior to occur twice.


==
in sum: if you can insert a two-step process with a confirmation page, do it.

If you cannot

and you can deal with some wiggle room (meaning this is not an unsubscription process where you cannot just "miss" a click) until tested properly with some real behavior  end-to-end

and if you have some time to engineer a setup for a specific email


...then you can play around with the below. It has its limits, but might help in some scenarios.
==
solution approach
find below a handler page that users dont have to confirm, but that tries and sanitizes "bot clicks" on its own.
It is meant to tackle both issues listed above.
Short order of operations:
0 get incoming link params, including the actual target destination URL.
1 always track all clicks in a DE
2 if a click is found for a honeypot link we placed in the email (= a link that only a parsing bot would find - because its 1x1px big element), we mark the log entry as "sanitizedClick" and wont react further. Best place the honeypot ABOVE your actual link, so your actual clicks falls under 3.
This is to prevent "click all links" bots from triggering our business process
3 if a click is tracked, and the page finds another click from same sent event just seconds ago in the logfile, we also mark the log entry as "sanitizedClick" and wont react further.
This is to prevent MS safelinks type tools to trigger our business process twice systematically.
limits:
You will see this logic is somewhat fuzzy as it is finds duplicates by recency in seconds. So a "wrong" click might make it through or once in a while, or you might miss a real one and have to monitor in the log to optimize the threshold:
==
details:
In short, set up a cloudpage:
Target that cloudpage with your link in question, and include the actual target URL as a base64 encoded parameter fwd
In your email, place a 1x1 px element that links to a made up page called "whatever your client or system....com/honeypot"
encrypt the subscriber key in your email and send it in parameter subscriberKey.
also send jobId, listId and batchId in these params: jid/lid/bid
%%[ /* clickTrackingHandler */ ]%%
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core",1)
var clickTrackingHandlerLogDE = "clickTrackingHandlerLog"

// fill these in
var pw = "external key of the pw used to encrypt"
var salt = "external key of the salt used to encrypt"
var IV = "external key of the IV used to encrypt"


// functions
/* assuming you placed a dummy 1px link somewhere towards the top of the email 
that contains the word "honeypot", this function will recognize it.
Assuming someone clicks that, they are very likely a bot that clicks all links. 
*/
function containsHoneyPot(forwardLink) {
    if (forwardLink && typeof forwardLink === 'string') {
        return forwardLink.toLowerCase().indexOf('honeypot') !== -1;
    }
    return false;
}

function decryptSymmetric(string,algorithm,password_key,password,salt_key,salt,vector_key,vector) {
    var varName = '@amp__DecryptSymmetric',
        param = [algorithm,password_key,password,salt_key,salt,vector_key,vector];
    var amp = "\%\%[ ";      
    amp += "set "+varName+" = DecryptSymmetric(";
    amp += "'" + string + "'";
    for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        var value = (param[i]) ? "'"+param[i]+"'" : '@null';
        amp += "," + value;    
    }
    amp += ") ";
    amp += "output(concat("+varName+")) ";
    amp += "]\%\%";
    return Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(amp);
}


/* we track every click to a DE.
but before we do, we check in that if we have another entry within a couple seconds, assumed here: 5 seconds
If not, we have a normal "click"
In case we find already a click within that threshold, we assume the current one to be duplicate (think MS safelinks) and mark it accordingly ("sanitizedClick").
We likely only want to process the "click" and do nothing if sanitized.
*/
function findDuplicateOrTest(subscriberKey, jobId, listId, batchId) {
    if(!subscriberKey) {
        // this is a preview or test, dont process
        return true
    }

    var lookupDE = DataExtension.Init(clickTrackingHandlerLogDE);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var threshold = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - 5000);  // 5 seconds
    var filter = {
        Property: "subscriberKey",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: subscriberKey
    };

    var data = lookupDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    //Write(Stringify(data))
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].jobId == jobId && data[i].listId == listId && data[i].batchId == batchId) {
            var entryTime = new Date(data[i].timestampServertime);
            if (entryTime > threshold) { // if another click from the exact same send event is found within x seconds, 
                Write("\r\n"+Stringify(currentTime))
                Write("\r\n"+Stringify(threshold))
                Write("\r\n"+"too soon")
                return true; // Recent duplicate found, don't process
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // No recent duplicate found, process
}
// end functions

var encryptedSubscriberKey = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("subscriberKey")
var forwardLink = Base64Decode(Request.GetQueryStringParameter("fwd"))
var jobId = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("jid")
var listId = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("lid")
var batchId = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("bid")    

var subscriberKey = ""

if(encryptedSubscriberKey) {
    try {

        subscriberKey = decryptSymmetric(encryptedSubscriberKey,"AES",pw,null,salt,null,IV,null)        
        Write(subscriberKey)
        
        var rowkey = Platform.Function.GUID()
        if (findDuplicateOrTest(subscriberKey, jobId, listId, batchId)
        || containsHoneyPot(forwardLink)
        ) {

            // we either see click on the honeypot (which we sanitize) 
            // or a duplicate click within seconds (which we sanitize)
            Write("test / empty subscriberKey or duplicate blocked")
            var event = "sanitizedClick"
        } else {
            Write("valid")
            var event = "click"
            
            // perform what you actually want to do for valid clicks.

        }

        Platform.Function.InsertData(clickTrackingHandlerLogDE
            ,["rowkey","event","subscriberKey","jobId","listId","batchId","forwardLink","data"]
            ,[rowkey,event,subscriberKey,jobId,listId,batchId,forwardLink,Stringify(dataObject)]
        );

    } catch(e) {
        Platform.Function.InsertData(clickTrackingHandlerLogDE
            ,["rowkey","event","subscriberKey","jobId","listId","batchId","forwardLink","data"]
            ,[rowkey,"catch",subscriberKey,jobId,listId,batchId,forwardLink,Stringify(e)]
        );
    }   
} else {
    Platform.Function.InsertData(clickTrackingHandlerLogDE
        ,["rowkey","event","subscriberKey","jobId","listId","batchId","forwardLink","data"]
        ,[rowkey,"invalidData",subscriberKey,jobId,listId,batchId,forwardLink,""]
    );
}
Platform.Response.Redirect(forwardLink)
</script>


